# Display doesn't turns off when playing an audio file in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio, display

When playing an audio file in Windows 8 (in windows media player or vlc) with normal power plan, my display doesn't turns off automatically which is set to be off in 5 minutes when idle even if there is any folder window (other than windows media player window) on my screen.
Is it a options or settings problem or else.
I am using on Dell laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the advanced options for your powerplan, there should be something about media files allowing hibernate/sleep.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Searching on this site I got an answer for Windows Media Player (going in Tools -> Options -> Player Tab -> Allow screen saver during playback) and it works, but I need this type of settings for VLC player too as my default media player is vlc, could you help me in that?